# rosrun rviz rviz -> Segmentation fault

Tags: rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been told that my error is different from the post where I have originally asked this questions. Since I still have this problem I would like to ask for help in this topic then. When I try to run rviz "Segmentation fault" error. I'm using 10.4 (running on vmware) and electric:

```
user@ubuntu:~/.rviz$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1321935622.778521758]: rviz revision number 1.6.6
[ INFO] [1321935622.778786716]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1321935622.778826499]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1321935622.887818975]: Loading general config from [/home/user/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1321935622.888264749]: Loading display config from [/home/user/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1321935622.966972423]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ INFO] [1321935623.281105694]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
Segmentation fault
```

I tried to remove lines in display_config - it didn't help. I removed both configs and got the same results. I was trying to restart workstation and turtlebot but it didn't help either. One or two times I had different error which actually did come up here as well:

```
user@ubuntu:~/.rviz$ rosrun rviz rviz -d 'rospack find turtlebot_interactive_markers'/config/interactive_markers.vcg 
[ INFO] [1321935611.525499608]: rviz revision number 1.6.6
[ INFO] [1321935611.525703015]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1321935611.525739543]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1321935611.639785830]: Loading general config from [/home/user/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1321935611.640200506]: Loading display config from [/home/user/.rviz/display_config]
[ INFO] [1321935611.700409981]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
The program 'rviz' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter)'.
  (Details: serial 21 error_code 9 request_code 55 minor_code 0)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Any ideas (other than remove files)? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12043/rosrun-rviz-rviz--%3E-segmentation-fault/) by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2011-11-22

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2011-12-01**:
Yeah but this doesn't even work on my machine natively (it has an Intel GMA945)

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2011-11-23**:
I've run glxinfo and it has "direct rendering: Yes". Does anyone else has tried to run rviz on VMWare? Is this a problem?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-22**:
A minimal test is the output of glxinfo. It should say: direct rendering: Yes
VirtualBox has experimental 3D support, I don't know about VM (and if rviz works in virtualbox).

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2011-11-22**:
Is there a way to test it and find out if this is the case?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-22**:
3D support for virtual machines is quite limited and rviz uses Ogre. Maybe, it just won't work.

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2011-11-22**:
Yes. Does it make any difference? Let me include this in the question.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-22**:
Are you running in a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't get rviz to run reliably in a Parallels or VirtualBox VM. It definitely seems to be Ogre-related. I think you might be out of luck. :(

---

Originally posted by [Alaina](https://answers.ros.org/users/767/alaina/) with karma: 121 on 2011-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2011-11-23**:
I've installed ogre separately and didn't have any problems with it. I'm running vmware with 2 cores and 2 gb of memory for it but I'm not getting even close to 100% utilization or memory usage. Ubuntu is 10.4. Not sure what else I can check.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for bringing it up again, but I've tried to used NOT virtual ubuntu and got different output(wxWidgets Error ) with the same result(Segmentation fault) :

```
user@ubuntu:~$ rosrun rviz rviz
[ INFO] [1322545025.559671268]: rviz revision number 1.6.7
[ INFO] [1322545025.559806709]: ogre_tools revision number 1.6.2
[ INFO] [1322545025.559826350]: compiled against OGRE version 1.7.3 (Cthugha)
[ INFO] [1322545028.702059076]: Loading general config from [/home/user/.rviz/config]
[ INFO] [1322545028.702415224]: Loading display config from [/home/user/.rviz/display_config]

[ WARN] [1322545028.749687273]: wxWidgets Warning [Application built with libpng-1.2.42 but running with 1.5.4]
[ERROR] [1322545028.749953503]: wxWidgets Error [Couldn't load a PNG image - file is corrupted or not enough memory.]

[ INFO] [1322545028.784673124]: RTT Preferred Mode is PBuffer.
[ INFO] [1322545042.966015806]: Texture for pass 0: creating with size 1 x 1
Segmentation fault
```

However, I can start rviz from turtlebot itself(but it works very slow, especially when I was trying to build point cloud 2d data - it freezed)  Any ideas on how I can solve this problem? Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) with karma: 131 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2011-12-01**:
I'm getting something like one-in-ten success rate when exporting OGRE_RTT_MODE to Copy or FBO, but it's still not coming up 100% of the time. Additional info here: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4830#comment:19

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-12-01**:
Glad it helped. So you can now help me by answering how exactly you did it here: http://answers.ros.org/question/3107/how-to-run-rviz-with-ogre_rtt_mode-set-to-copy-or . I for now ended up reverting to diamondback. Cheers.

**Comment by [Roman Burdakov](https://answers.ros.org/users/1201/roman-burdakov/) on 2011-12-01**:
Tom, thanks a lot for your comment. Now it works. I tried Copy and FBO modes before I was getting wxWidgets Error (my original post) and it didn't work out. When I removed video driver glxinfo started working, and I've got wxWidgets. Changing mode to Copy after and trying to run few times helped.

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-11-29**:
I'm having the same problem. I was just reading http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting -> 3.4. It says one could try running rviz with OGRE_RTT_MODE set to "Copy" or "FBO", instead of the default "PBuffer", but I don't know how. Do you? I'm on ros-electric, 10.04. using mesa openGL drivers.